# Dijkstra recursive java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, recursion, dijkstra, stack-overflow

Im trying to write Dijkstra's algorithm recursively. But I keep getting this `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

It uses `PixelNode`s which have a grayscale value and a `x,y` coordinate. The neighbors function returns max 3 `PixelNode`s, the 3 pixels below the current pixel s.

```
public PixelNode Dijkstra(PixelNode s, PriorityQueue<PixelNode> leads) {
  s.visited = true;
  if (s.isEndNode) {
    return s;
  }
  ArrayList<PixelNode> nbs = s.neighbors();
  for (PixelNode nb : nbs) {
    if (!nb.visited) {
      float new_distance = s.distance + nb.val();
      if (new_distance < nb.distance) {
        nb.distance = new_distance;
        nb.via = s;
      }
      if (!nb.addedToLeads) {
        nb.addedToLeads=true;
        leads.add(nb);
      } else {
        leads.remove(nb);
        leads.add(nb);
      }
    }
  }
  return Dijkstra(leads.poll(), leads);
}
```

If someone would be so kind to help me, it will be much appreciated!

EDIT:
leads.remove(nb) is not working. Didn't override the equals function of PixelNode properly. Now I have overridden it properly it is still not removing though...

EDIT:
I'm starting to think it has reached max recursion depth. If I crop the image real small it finds the right path... For an image of 21x19 it needs 374 recursions. Roughly the nr of pixels in the image. The real image is 396x366. I guess it needs 396x366=144936 recursive function calls. It breaks at 3257 calls.

The new version of the function is now:

```
public PixelNode dijkstra(PixelNode s, PriorityQueue<PixelNode> leads) {
  s.visited=true;
  if(s.isEndNode) {
    return s;
  }
  ArrayList<PixelNode> nbs = s.neighbors();
  for(PixelNode nb : nbs) {
    if(!nb.visited) {
      float new_distance = s.distance + nb.val();
      if(new_distance < nb.distance) {
        nb.distance = new_distance;
        nb.via = s;
        nb.addedToLeads = true;
        leads.add(nb);
      }
    }
  }
  return dijkstra(leads.poll(), leads);
}
```

Comment: The name of the exception `StackOverflowError` never feels/looks serious to me anymore :)

Comment: Are you sure any one of the node set to `s.isEndNode = true`

Comment: If the index of pixel s is in the bottom row of the image it should stop searching. s.isEndNode = (s.i >= (img.pixels.length - img.width) && s.i < img.pixels.length)

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have source code to reproduce the problem, I have to guess:

```
public PixelNode Dijkstra(PixelNode s, PriorityQueue<PixelNode> leads) {
  s.visited = true;
  if (s.isEndNode) {
    return s;
  }
  ArrayList<PixelNode> nbs = s.neighbors();
  for (PixelNode nb : nbs) {
    if (!nb.visited) {
      float new_distance = s.distance + nb.val();
      if (new_distance < nb.distance) {
        if (nb.addedToLeads) {
          // already in leads with higher distance value
          // Note: remove is done before distance update
          leads.remove(nb);
        }
        nb.distance = new_distance;
        nb.via = s;
      } else if (nb.addedToLeads) {
        // already in leads with lower or equal distance value
        continue;
      }
      nb.addedToLeads=true;
      leads.add(nb);
    }
  }
  return Dijkstra(leads.poll(), leads);
}
```

Also make sure your Comparator for PriorityQueue returns correct values for equals.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I figured a removal is not needed really since the new insertion will be higher in the queue. I think it will never poll its 'clone' with the higher distance.